# Effect of <table> border-collapse: collapse; on the box shadow in IE browsers

Tags: html, css

i created the table with empty span tags with padding giving them a box shadow.
its simple html structure is as follow.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="tokenHolder" data-ans="5" style="padding: 2px 53.5px;"></span></td>
        <td><span class="tokenHolder" data-ans="5" style="padding: 2px 53.5px;"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="tokenHolder" data-ans="5" style="padding: 2px 53.5px;"></td></span>
        <td><span class="tokenHolder" data-ans="5" style="padding: 2px 53.5px;"></span></td>    
    </tr>
 </table>
```

with css code as below..

```
th {
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        padding: 5px 8px;
    }

    td {
        padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #ececec;
    }       

    th,td {
        border-right: 2px solid #dedcdd;            
    }       

    table {
        margin-top: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #dedcdd;
        position: relative;         
        border-collapse: collapse;  
    }

    .tokenHolder {
        background-color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        color: transparent;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
        border-radius: 2px;         
    }
```

the respective js fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/Pank/4A9BM/

here in after using border-collapse:collapse at the table removes the box shadow for the span inside it..

otherwise hole code is running fine in all browsers..

Please help for this ie related quirk..

Comment: Yeeee...Got the answer with adding attribute rules=none instead of using border-collapse: collapse;

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<!doctype html>
```

in the top of your HTML document. It will work fine. Tested in IE10

updated answer.

screen shot: When i use 
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2440-42.html

Screen shot: without using 
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2440-43.html

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2440-44.html

here is the link to it. just read it. 
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

Comment: for sure, its not a issue of doctype i checked...its related to the effect of border-collapse: collapse;  css property applied to the table to its children span tags

Comment: just check out my edits and the links which i have added it might help you.